# error when python pip install rrdtool on windows 7

Tags: python, windows, pip, installation, rrdtool

I am running windows 7 64 bit, Python v2.7.10 and pip v9.0.1

I tried to install rrdtool but I get an error

```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> pip install rrdtool
Collecting rrdtool
  Using cached rrdtool-0.1.11.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    test_rrdtool.c
    c:\users\person\appdata\local\temp\tmp_python_rrdtoolvwty3u\test_rrdtool.c(2) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open incl
ude file: 'rrd.h': No such file or directory
    Error: Unable to compile the binary module. Do you have the rrdtool header and libraries installed?

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\person\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-pyontu\rrdt
ool\
```

I also tried to install python-rrdtool but got an error

```
    PS C:\Users\person\Downloads> pip install python-rrdtool
Collecting python-rrdtool
  Using cached python-rrdtool-1.4.7.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: python-rrdtool
  Running setup.py install for python-rrdtool ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\person\
\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-ykegvz\\python-rrdtool\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.re
ad().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\person\appdata\lo
cal\temp\pip-w44bef-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    running build_configure
    building 'rrdtoolmodule' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\rrdtool-1.4.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\rrdtool-1.4.7\bindings
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\rrdtool-1.4.7\bindings\python
    C:\Users\person\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O
x /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Irrdtool-1.4.7/src -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcrrdtool-1.4.7/bindings/python/rrdt
oolmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\rrdtool-1.4.7/bindings/python/rrdtoolmodule.obj
    rrdtoolmodule.c
    rrdtool-1.4.7/bindings/python/rrdtoolmodule.c(41) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: '../../rrd_config.h
': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\person\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin
\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\person\\appdata\\local\\temp\\p
ip-build-ykegvz\\python-rrdtool\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n
');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\person\appdata\local\temp\pip-w44bef-reco
rd\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\person\appdat
a\local\temp\pip-build-ykegvz\python-rrdtool\
```

I ran the installation using admin privileges as well but get the same error.

I need to parse some rrd files using the rrdtool and create graphs but I just cannot install this archive using pip.

I am a newbie with python so I am not sure how to go about this.

I tried to install it using tar.gz file downloaded from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-rrdtool/1.4.7 still got an error

```
PS C:\Users\person\Downloads> pip install .\python-rrdtool-1.4.7.tar.gz
Processing c:\users\person\downloads\python-rrdtool-1.4.7.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: python-rrdtool
  Running setup.py install for python-rrdtool ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\person\
\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-hpkobh-build\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r
\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\person\appdata\local\temp\pip-b3z
3rd-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    running build_configure
    building 'rrdtoolmodule' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\rrdtool-1.4.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\rrdtool-1.4.7\bindings
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\rrdtool-1.4.7\bindings\python
    C:\Users\person\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O
x /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Irrdtool-1.4.7/src -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcrrdtool-1.4.7/bindings/python/rrdt
oolmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\rrdtool-1.4.7/bindings/python/rrdtoolmodule.obj
    rrdtoolmodule.c
    rrdtool-1.4.7/bindings/python/rrdtoolmodule.c(41) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: '../../rrd_config.h
': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\person\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin
\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\person\\appdata\\local\\temp\\p
ip-hpkobh-build\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exe
c(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\person\appdata\local\temp\pip-b3z3rd-record\install-recor
d.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\person\appdata\local\temp\pip
-hpkobh-build\
```

Comment: Do you have the rrdtool header and libraries installed?

Comment: how do I get that?? do you mean I need install the rrdtool from rrdtool.org

Comment: no idea. I think you _know_ what you're trying to install... You could search for `rrdtool`'s official website or GitHub.

Comment: I cannot find a compiled library that I can find for the rrdtool that works. Only option looks to building it manually but I don't know how to do that now. I found the github link https://github.com/oetiker/rrdtool-1.x but how do I go about this now?

Answer (score 0):

You can download it manually from [website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-rrdtool/1.4.7)
then go to folder with .tar.gz and execute command `pip install python-rrdtool-1.4.7.tar.gz`

You can also try to download it from [here](http://www.cacti.net/downloads/rrdtool/win32/) unzip and start `.exe` file.

Comment: This did not work I posted the error on the details section

Comment: I switched to ubuntu for now but I need help figuring out how to get the windows side working.

Answer (score 0):

When facing the error message

> Error: Unable to compile the binary module

you'll need to ensure `rrdtool` is installed. It seems it's impossible to install the `rrdtool-python` module without the underlying `libs/binaries/headers` already existing on your filesystem.

In general, installing the following packages on your machine should resolve this issue:

- rrdtool
- rrdtool-devel

for my specific use-case in RHEL8, installing the following allowed rrdtool-python to install smoothly:

- rrdtool-1.7.0-16.el8.x86_64.rpm
- rrdtool-devel-1.7.0-16.el8.x86_64.rpm