# Is there a reason for pip to support only version 1.4.7 of rrdtool (and not the latest, 1.6.0)?

Tags: python, pip, rrdtool

We want to use version 1.6.0 and have to install it by running:

```
wget http://ftp.?.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/rrdtool/python-rrdtool_1.6.0-1+b2_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.?.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/rrdtool/librrd8_1.6.0-1+b2_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.?.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libp/libpng1.6/libpng16-16_1.6.28-1_amd64.deb

dpkg -i libpng16-16_1.6.28-1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i librrd8_1.6.0-1+b2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i python-rrdtool_1.6.0-1+b2_amd64.deb
```

Because pip supports only version 1.4.7. Is there a reason for that, that we should take into consideration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be 2 packages on pypi - [`rrdtool`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rrdtool/0.1.11) & [`python-rrdtool`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-rrdtool). The latter (one you are probably using) seems like an old & abandoned library, hence the version.

Comment: There's this issue with rrdtool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046222/error-when-python-pip-install-rrdtool-on-windows-7 (on ubuntu as well)

Comment: I found that I have to run this: 'sudo apt-get install librrd-dev libpython-dev' before running 'pip install rrdtool' and it seem to work (source: http://pythonhosted.org/rrdtool/install.html#debian-ubuntu). Thanks!